# PowerPoint fullscreen crashes with PlayonLinux

Tags: playonlinux, microsoft-powerpoint

I have installed playonlinux 4.0.14 on my Ubuntu. I successfully installed Powerpoint 2010 that launches after setting riched20.dll to native in the Winecfg. However when i am putting a presentation in full screen the whole system crashed and a black screen is shown. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Which version (32bit/64bit) are you trying to install? (Also, Libreoffice Impress works better than PowerPoint for most stuff). More information if possible would be helpful

Comment: 32bit version in 32bit machine

Comment: It is a bug, presumably in PlayonLinux (although it could be your GPU drivers). I would recommend reporting it as a bug to PlayOnLinux.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug of your currently used `wine` version. So try a different version of `wine`. Playonlinux has an option that will allow install many version of wine. So install the latest version and associate it with powerpoint.

Comment: I've installed Wine 1.7.22 and everything works perfectly!

Comment: @curious So your bounty will not lost.